# Can i use my A/C with the front panel/lid just a little bit open?

Tags: hvac, sounds

Using my AC with the front panel/lid just a little bit open prevents it from doing a horrendous sound.

Is it ok to use it like that?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I've done that myself. As long as that door normally opens.

Comment: I don’t see a problem it may affect the efficiency . Did you check the screw on the squirt cage blower? If that is loose and it keeps free spinning it will ruin the shaft and a new motor will be needed if that is the cause.

Comment: i have note done that, can i do it myself?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica thanks